# Group by Member but Order by Count Product

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display promos from all members in the order of the highest number of clicks in the last 1 week, terms that 1 member only displays 1 promo
like this:

| id promo | member/sales | order by count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | B | 10 |
| 5 | A | 9 |
| 6 | M | 8 |

The following is the data table

Tabel Promo (product_promo)>>  | ppo_id  | ppo_sales  | ppo_content |

Tabel click recording (ipslsprod) >> | idip | dipp (id promo) | mxd (datetime visit click)

Tabel sales (sales) >> | id  | name |

And I've written down the code

```
SELECT pp.*,
       s.*,
       Count(ip.dipp) AS VIEWS
FROM   product_promo pp
       left join (SELECT *
                  FROM   ipslsprod
                  WHERE  mxd >= Date_sub(Now(), interval 7 day)) ip
              ON ip.dipp = pp.ppo_id
       left join sales s
              ON pp.ppo_sales = s.id
GROUP  BY pp.ppo_id
ORDER  BY VIEWS DESC
```

But showing more than 1 member

| id promo | member/sales | order by count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | B | 10 |
| 5 | A | 9 |
| 4 | B | 7 |

I've tried changing

GROUP BY pp.ppo_sales

The data is messy.

Please help and instructions,

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions involved...)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh hi i have updated my question

Comment: Your current GROUP BY is invalid and should raise an error. However, older MySQL versions don't, and instead returns a somewhat arbitrary result. Are you using MySQL? Which version?

Comment: @jarlh MySQL version 5.0.8

Comment: You need a subquery to get _1 product_promo in the order of the highest number of ip.dipps_. JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh is there an example code?

Comment: Well, let's try again: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display each sales only 1 product_promo in the order of the highest number of ip.dipps.

You can use aggregation and window functions.  I'm not sure exactly what the query is, but I think:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT s.id, pp.id_product_promo, COUNT(*) AS views ,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sales s JOIN
           product_promo pp 
           ON pp.ppo_sales = s.id JOIN
           ipslsprod ip
           ON ip.dipp = pp.ppo_id
      WHERE ip.mxd >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 day)) ip  
      GROUP BY s.id, pp.id_product_promo
     ) v
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but this doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" is useless.  What happens?  Do you get an error?  Does it produce incorrect results?  Did it cause the electricity to fail?

Comment: OP is using MySQL version 5.0.8.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will enlighten a bit more:

```
SELECT your_fields, MAX(count_click) FROM [table] GROUP BY count_click ORDER BY count_click
```

From there you can add all the date related stuff to fine-tune the query.

Perhaps it is a good idea to read up on the MySQL INTERVAL for that.

Comment: thanks for the information, that's not the point, i just want to show 1 member 1 promotion or not duplicate member. And count clicks is taken from the visitor record on ipslsprod